# Что лучше использовать для value - const или let?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот конкретный пример:

```js
const out6 = document.querySelector('.out-6');
const input6 = document.querySelector('.i-6');
let a6 = '';

function t6() {
    const value = +input6.value;

    for (let i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        a6 += '******<br>'
    }
    out6.innerHTML = a6;
}
document.querySelector('.b-6').onclick = t6;
```

```html
<div><input type="number" class="i-6"></div>
<button class="button-primary b-6">Запуск</button>
<div class="out-6"></div>
```

`const` подразумевает то, что значение переменной не будет дальше изменено.

Но мне не совсем понятно что считать за изменение. Фактически мы не переопределяем значение `value`, но оно может быть изменено, если мы будем вводить разные значения в `input`.

Поэтому я не понимаю: что лучше использовать в данном случае - `let` или `const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменение - это **явное** присваиванием нового значение.

В коде есть только одно присваивание, при инициализации

```
const value = +input6.value;
```

следовательно, достаточно использовать `const`.

В противном случае будет ошибка при попытке присвоить новое значение константе и нужно будет в любом случае менять `const` на `let`.

Answer (score 4):

> Фактически мы не переопределяем значение `value`, но оно может быть изменено, если мы будем вводить разные значения в input.

На всякий случай: если вдруг вы предположили, что `value` будет меняться каждый раз, как вы введёте что-то новое в `input`, то это не так. Когда вы присваиваете переменной примитивное значение (например, число или строку), она не сохраняет связь и источником значения, так что в данном случае переменная не изменится, что бы вы не вводили в поле. Если бы вы присвоили переменной непримитивное значение, например — сам элемент input, то связь бы возникла, с каждым изменением свойств элемента менялись бы и свойства объекта в переменной, потому что объекты присваиваются по ссылке, а не копируются, это был бы один и тот же объект. Но и в этом случае вы могли бы использовать `const`, потому что переменная всё равно ссылалась бы на один и тот же объект, независимо от перемены его свойств.

Answer (score 1):

`const` - когда переменная не будет меняться. Также можно применять для ссылочных переменных, таких как `object`.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

> Поэтому я не понимаю: что лучше использовать в данном случае - let или const?

В решении аналогичных вопросов можно использовать простое правило... Не знаешь что писать `let` или `const` - пиши `const`.

Если в процессе тестирования нарываешься на ошибку типа `Assignment to constant variable` - заменяешь `const` на `let`.

Конкретно в случае ТСа - однозначно `const`, поскольку в переменной содержится ссылка на элемент ДОМ и она не изменяется. Пример работает и ошибок не выдает.